# Can std::vector or some other dynamic container which allows iterating reside partially in RAM and swap (Linux)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, stdvector

I have a text processing application which uses `std::vector` in its code to store huge arrays, tables, etc. When I do mining of huge texts, the application crashes when meets a rim of RAM, without entering swap.

Unfortunately, crash message is not informative, it's just segfault. There are a lot of possibilities to investigate with debugger of course, but *regardless* of this situation, I became curious about one thing which caught my attention in [the explanation of how `std::vector` works](https://www.quora.com/C++-programming-language-Does-std-vector-use-stack-or-heap-memory-and-why):

> whenever you declare a vector object, it reserves some contiguous
>   space in memory.  And if during an insertion, its exceeds that
>   capacity, it will create new space with a buffer in memory, copy the
>   data from the vector, insert the new data, and destroy older memory.
>
> If your program is going to do lot of insertion and deletion, use
>   std::list.

Could it be, that when application (and I am interested in `std::vector` in particular) requests creating a contiguous object which exceeds RAM size and even though there is a place in the swap, it throws error?

Can I operate a dynamic array which resides in both RAM and swap with `std::list` or some other container?

---

Thanks everyone and sorry for the noob question! That's not my program and I was just trying to make it working, and that idea of made me curious. So looks like it's just a coincidence that it crashes when approaches the size of RAM which is equal to mine.

Comment: No, the way how `std::list` stores the data is fundamentally different than how it's done with `std::vector` or other container classes, so they can't be _swapped_.

Comment: Swapping is transparent for application, you dont need any containers for it to work. So `std::vector` is able to do that. You just have a bug in your program.

Comment: Also "contiguous" here has nothing to do with the amount of RAM you have.

Comment: @Ivan So that means the program can allocate a memory space bigger than physical RAM (but less than RAM+swap) and this won't cause any errors?

Comment: Even if you would be running out of memory, vector would not segfault. Instead, it would throw `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: @Slowpoke, due to peculiarities of OS, programs can sometime allocate even more :D

Comment: "If your program is going to do lot of insertion and deletion, use std::list." Not necessarily. It depends a lot on where in the container you are inserting and deleting. There are containers that specialize. `vector` is the tool of choice if primarily working on the end. `deque` rules if you are working on the beginning or the end. `list` does high speed insert and delete anywhere in the list, but finding where to perform the insert very often annihilates the performance improvement.

Comment: @Slowpoke it is entirely possible that they are still related. The `bad_alloc` exception can be caught and mishandled, leaving the size unchanged and the program writing into space it thinks it's allocated. Silly thing to do, but doable.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks! I see already that I should investigate the code step by step, I will create output at all the stages and find where it crashes then.

Comment: @BoPersson No, everything is 64bit, it crashes when reaches entire RAM which is 32GB (and there is additional 32 GB of swap).

Comment: @Slowpoke - Ok. A vector usually grows by a factor 1.5-2 each time it has to reallocate. So if it already is 32GB, it will try to allocate perhaps 48GB and copy the old contents to the new storage. For a short while, it holds 32+48 GB before releasing the old part. This could overflow the swap file.

Comment: @Slowpoke If you are allocating this much RAM, you shouldn't be using `std::vector` as it is bad for handling large allocations. If you are using Linux you should consider using `mmap` and `mremap` functions directly. `mremap` will allow you to increase allocated blockwithout copying any data at all. If you are not running on Linux, using simple `std::malloc`, `std::realloc` might get you better results as you will be able to skip memory initialization.

Comment: You may hit the ulimit.

Comment: @BoPersson Thanks! Could you please give me an advice on the container I can use to replace std::vector in this particular case? I don't see and the moment any complicated usage of the container in the code, just iteration.

Comment: @Ivan Thanks! But if it's C++, maybe it's it already implemented in some std container? With functions like `points.push_back()`, iteration `for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); ++ i) {do_something(points[i])}`, and possibility to create nested ones `vector<vector<double>> `?

Comment: @Slowpoke No, there is nothing is standard C++ to handle large allocations efficiently, at least don't want to give us on contiguous memory. Splitting allocations in many smaller regions is the best you can do. Probably something like `std::deque<std::vector<T>>`.

Comment: @Ivan I don't think contiguous regions are needed there, from what I can see looking at the code of the modules, the program just iterates those vectors in loops doing clustering, sorting, segmentation, etc. Thanks for the suggestion! I think I can try to make those loops work with iterator for `std::deque`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap is transparent to program operation. Whenever your program is actually using a particular page of memory it will be brought into main memory  but at any other time the OS is free to move it to swap and your program will simply remain unaware of that fact.

A segfault indicates that you are trying to access an invalid address (either for reading or writing).

Comment: Thanks very much! So swap is just extending addresses and OS does not prevent application to allocate a single memory block which is bigger than physical RAM. Ok, thanks! Please excuse me if this question was too noob, and this application is not mine, I am just trying to use it.